# two txt files data how to getting and merge based on customerid how to getting the two txt files data using with node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sorting

i am newly learner nodejs developer

**i have two txt files like file1.txt and file2.txt file1.text data is different and file2.txt data is different but customerid is same beased on customerid id how to getting two files data**

```
file1.txt data is:
[{'customerid':12,
'name':'xyz',
'email':'test@gmail.com'
},
{'customerid':14,
'name':'def',
'email':'def@gmail.com'
},
{'customerid':15,
'name':'pqr',
'email':'pqr@gmail.com'}
,{'customerid':17,
'name':'abc',
'email':'abc@gmail.com'}]

file2.txt data is:
[{
' customerid':12,
 'vachilenum':26789,
 'price':390900920,
 "phone":673648494894
 },
 {'customerid':14,
 'vachilenum':26789,
 'price':390900920,
 "phone":673648494894
 },
 {'customerid':15,
 'vachilenum':26789,
 'price':390900920,
 "phone":673648494894
 },
 {'customerid':17,
 'vachilenum':26789,
 'price':390900920,
 "phone":673648494894
 }];
```

i am trying this code but iam not getting expected out put any one please suggest me

```
const arr1 = fs.readFileSync('file1.txt', 'utf8').toString();
console.log(arr1)
const arr2 = fs.readFileSync('file2.text', 'utf8').toString();
console.log(arr2)

const merge = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const temp = []

  arr1.forEach(x => {
    arr2.forEach(y => {
      if (x.id === y.id) {
        temp.push({ ...x, ...y })
      }
    })
  })

  return temp
}
console.log(merge(arr1, arr2))




   expected outputt is
       {'customerid':12,
        'name':'xyz',
        'email':'test@gmail.com'
        'vachilenum':26789,
         'price':390900920,
         "phone":673648494894
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `map` function in combination with `find` and return the merged object.
Also, you may wanna parse the file content to a JSON object:

```
const arr1 = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('file1.txt', 'utf8'));
console.log(arr1);
const arr2 = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('file2.text', 'utf8'));
console.log(arr2);

const merge = (arr1, arr2) => {
  return arr1.map(x => {
    const y = arr2.find(val => val.customerid === x.customerid);
    if (!y) return x;
    return { ...x, ...y }
  })
};

console.log(merge(arr1, arr2));
```

Comment: tq somuch i am try this above code i am getting TypeError: arr1.map is not a function error

Comment: Did you add the `JSON.parse` function?

Comment: No please help me once how to add

Comment: Just copy the answer's code

Comment: great .....got it tq so much

Comment: You needed to parse the file content to JSON. Otherwise, it would not have been recognized as an array.